# Java: is happening automatic wrapping?

Tags: java, format, autoboxing

Directly from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> s', 'S'   general     If the argument arg is null, then the result is
>   "null". If arg implements Formattable, then arg.formatTo is invoked.
>   Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking arg.toString().

Does it mean that in the following line of code the number 3 (arg) gets autoboxed in an Integer and then the method arg.toString() gets invoked?

```
 System.out.format("%10s",3);
```

Answer (score 1):

It does. All variadic arguments are autoboxed. And yes, `toString()` method is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can check yourself what happens exactly by compiling a small test program, and then decompiling it with `javap` (a tool included with the JDK):

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.format("%10s",3);
    }
}
```

Compile this with `javac Example.java` and then decompile it with `javap -c Example`:

```
Compiled from "Example.java"
public class Example {
  public Example();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String %10s
       5: iconst_1
       6: anewarray     #4                  // class java/lang/Object
       9: dup
      10: iconst_0
      11: iconst_3
      12: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      15: aastore
      16: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.format:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      19: pop
      20: return
}
```

You see what this does:

- It creates an `Object[]` in which first the string `"%10s"` is stored (lines 3-10)
- It calls `Integer.valueOf()` to box the value `3` (lines 11, 12)
- The `Integer` object is stored in the array (line 15)
- Then the method `format(Object[])` is called (line 16)

Note: The array is used because the `format` method is a varargs method; varargs are implemented using arrays.